# "User interaction" in the context of the USK

Tags: meaning-in-context, meaning

I was looking at the [USK](http://www.usk.de/en/classification/age-rating-symbols/) recommendation for a game that my children want to have. The game is [Roblox](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/p/roblox/9nblgggzm6wm?activetab=pivot:overviewtab). It has the rating USK12 due to

- violence
- digital purchases
- user interaction

I don't understand the term "user interaction" here. Every game needs to have user interaction, otherwise it wouldn't be a game, right?

So IMHO it has to be a special kind of user interaction. But what kind of user interaction could that be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More specifically online user interaction, PEGI observes it as 'Online'.

A bit of a misnomer, but it means potentially uncensored or supervised interaction between *other* users.